# Permission denied only with Workbench

Tags: mysql, fedora

I have a database located on a server and it is working correctly. I can access it from the local server and using phpmyadmin from any server connected to the network.

I would want to use Workbench in order to use its functions but I have tried a lot of possibilities and I'm not able to connect from it.

I have found a lot of solutions but anyone could not help me. For this reason, I'm trying to find someone who can help me with this.

First of all, I want to explain that this database is accessible from phpmyadmin (as I said before) and from webserver (I use database in my web application) so, the trouble of denied remote access is discarded. (with user root)

Furthermore I have looking for the problem and in the log of database server I have could find this:

```
error: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 failed: Permission denied
channel_by_id: 0: bad id
```

I have tried to use Workbench with TCP/IP with the IP of the database server by port 3306 and with SSH connecting to webserver (this step is running correctly) and connecting to database with local IP and port 3306.

Furthermore, I have checked if port 3306 was closed and it is opened.

The config (my.cnf) is this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
max_allowed_packet=1024M
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I know that this config is not usual but I have not installed it and I would not want to touch a lot because it is working now and a lot of people is using it.

I have tried too to edit `hosts.allow` adding the line `mysqld: all` but it did not work.

What can be the problem? Thanks for your help.

(I have checked Stackoverflow's posts too and I have not been able to find a solution)

Comment: Try https://superuser.com

Comment: Do you recommend me to create the same post there?

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure your mysql to allow remote login. then you can either specified your ip or wildcard * to allow all ip to access the mysql database.

this is the command to grant remote access.

Log in to the database server.
Connect to the MySQL database as the root user.
Enter the following command:

```
GRANT ALL ON <local database name>.* TO <remote web node username>@<remote web node server ip address> IDENTIFIED BY '<database user password>';
```

For example,

```
GRANT ALL ON magento_remote.* TO dbuser@192.0.2.50 IDENTIFIED BY 'dbuserpassword';
```

Comment: But I'm connecting there with webserver for example, is it not the same? And on IP, what IP should I have to put? Local IP or the IP that I want to connect from?

Comment: I have find it by doing `SHOW GRANTS;` -> `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' ...`. I have to create another one with my IP?